# Read REST query parameters in Java component

Tags: java, rest, talend

I am new to talend and need to implement a scenario using talend:

There is an endpoint `http://<HOST>:<PORT>/emp/{id}`  which fetches the employee data using the `id` value.
 I am using `tRESTRequest and tRESTResponse` components.

How can i get the `id` value in a java component connected to `tRESTRequest`?

Comment: If I get this right, you want to have a dynamic endpoint, where the id is a variable in your job ? Please detail your scenario. How is the id value retrieved ?

Answer (score 1):

In your tRESTRequest component

- Add an "Output Flow" in the "REST API MApping" section.
- Name the "Output Flow" `empid` with a field called `id`.
- In the REST API Mapping/ URI Pattern column, add `/emp/{id}/`

Now connect a tJavaRow component to the tRESTRequest, your id will be available as `input_row.id`.